# LaTeX justifies text when using itemize

Tags: lists

I would like to create a list that looks like this in LaTex:

```
1. Title of bullet point one

   description

2. Title of bullet point two

   description
```

I've tried doing so using this code:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Title of bullet point one\linebreak
    Text text text
    \item Title of bullet point two\linebreak
    Text text text
\end{itemize}
```

However, when I compile the code it ends up looking like this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Use `\newline` instead of `\linebreak`.

Comment: Instead of `\linebeak` (which is very very rarely used) you can also just make a new paragraph, aka exactly the same code as in your ascii example.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you so much @Skillmon and @daleif. I got it working!

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Title of bullet point one}\newline
            Text text text
    \item \textbf{Title of bullet point two}\newline
            Text text text
```